# JS Drawing Utility

Tags: javascript, html

I know this is a really bizzare request, but I need to have on my site, a drawing utility that allows the user to draw on an upscaled 28x28 canvas. It's so the user can draw the image on the website where it'll be put into a hand-written digit neural net and hopefully be correctly identified. The end result should look like the attached PNG file.

I've only used vanilla JS with my code down below. I tried setting the canvas to 28x28 but it gets too small to be actually usable, and upscaling makes the drawing functions non-functional

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var drawing = false;
var prev;

function clearCanvas() {
   context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    drawing = true;
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

   if (drawing) {
      var coord = { 'x': e.offsetX, 'y': e.offsetY };
      if (prev !== undefined) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);
        context.lineTo(coord.x, coord.y);
        context.stroke();
      }
      prev = coord;
   }
});

 canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
   drawing = false;
   prev = undefined;
});
```

This is what it should look like:

[image: This is what it should look like]

Comment: if it's 28 times 28 why not create a grid of that size, which "colors" the cells upon mouse move?

Comment: If the upscaling is the issue, might be potentially easier to let people draw normally using something like [Fabric.js](https://fabricjs.com/freedrawing) and just downscale the canvas result to 28x28.